# QCalendarWidget currentdate

Tags: qt

как сделать в QCalendarWidget кнопку "today", так чтобы указатель в календаре переместился на текущую дату.

```
ui->calendarWidget = new QCalendarWidget();
    void MainWindow::on_todayPushButton_clicked()
    {
        model->setFilter(QString("exec_date = '%1'").arg(QDate::currentDate().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
       // как выделить сегодняшний день ?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Создать новую кнопку и разместить ее на виджете календаря, он ведь наследник QWidget и вам ничего мешает размещать на нем дочерние виджеты. Наверно лучше всего разместить кнопку на навигационной панели где находятся кнопки перелистывания, список месяцев и год:

```
auto today_button = new QPushButton(calendar);
auto navbar = calendar->findChild<QWidget>("qt_calendar_navigationbar");
assert(navbar);
navbar->getLayout()->addWidget(today_button);
```

Подключить сигналы к слотам, например так:

```
// простое перелистывание до текущей даты, вызовется сигнал
// QCalendarWidget::currentPageChanged
connect(  today_button, SIGNAL(  clicked())
        , calendar    , SLOT  (showToday()) );
```

Если нужно именно выставить текущую дату чтобы вызвался сигнал `QCalendarWidget::activated`, нужно использовать слот `QCalendarWidget::setSelectedDate` в который передать текущую дату. Но текущую дату должен кто-то сформировать. Тут может быть несколько вариантов:

Сделать `today_button` наследником `QPushButton` добавив в нее сигнал вида `void today(const QDate & date)` который по клику на кнопку формирует текущую дату, подключние будет таким:

```
connect(  today_button, &TodayButton    ::today
        , calendar    , &QCalendarWidget::setSelectedDate);
```

Отнаследовать `QCalendarWidget` добавив в него слот для установки текущей даты. Подключить этот слот к сигналу `QPushButton::clicked`.

Использовать третий промежуточный объект, который обрабатывает нажатие кнопки, формирует дату, и устанавливает ее в календарь.

И наконец самый простой и элегантный сопособ - подключить к сигналу кнопки ламбда-функцию (я их называю ламбда-слоты :)) которая и будет делать всю работу:

```
connect(  today_button, &QPushButton::clicked
        , [calendar]() -> void
          {
              auto today = QDate::currentDate();
              calendar->setSelectedDate(today);
          });
```

Comment: connect(  ui->todayPushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->calendarWidget , &QCalendarWidget::showToday ); не работает.

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov Исправил, попробуйте так.

Comment: Так синтаксис то правильный был.Просто ничего не происходит при нажатии. А теперь на " кавычки" ругается.

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov Сиправил. Пора заканчивать, на сегодня хватит =)